# prototype focus not work?

Tags: prototypejs

this snippet didn't work?

```
$('reply_form').show().focus();
```

and also this:

```
$('reply_form').show();Form.Element.focus('reply_form');
```

why?

#### updated

the element is a textarea with an id 'reply_form', and has a inline style with 'display:none;'(i know this is not a best practise, but writing the display style externally in a css file , the show function didn't work as the prototype doc said); the 'show()' part works, but the focus is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, it works well for me:

HTML code:

```
<textarea id="reply_form" style="display:none"></textarea>
```

JS code:

```
$('reply_form').show().focus();
```

And I'm using Prototype 1.6.0.3. What is your version of library?

Did you register any event action (onload, onclick) for this? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
document.getElementById('reply_form').focus();
```